# Is BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync required to update Live Tiles on the background?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I find different instructions, for making Live Tile of Windows 8.1 app update in the background using IBackgroundTask. Others include this row

`await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();`

others not.

Question is, is it required for the background updating of Live Tile to work? I do **NOT** need lock screen access in my app, just updating Live Tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run a lock-screen capable background task then you need to call the RequestAccessAsync().  Here are your options:

1. You can create a background task that updates the live tile doesn't need lock-screen access. If you want it to run periodically regardless of whether it is plugged in, you need to RequestAccessAsync().  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx) is a good article on when you should use the MaintinanceTrigger and the TimerTrigger.
2. You can update the live tile from your app directly.
3. You can create a periodic tile update using [TileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.startperiodicupdate.aspx)
4. In Windows 8.1, you can update the app's live tile using the TileUpdate element in the manifest (look at the Tile Update section on the Manifest Editor Application page.)
5. You can use push notification to update the live tile.

Comment: Can you please be more specific (bullet 1). My Live Tile is not updating when using background task if I haven't called RequestAccessAsync(). Should it work?

Comment: Here is a good article on the issue.  You would setup a MaintinanceTrigger instead of a TimeTrigger (which needs RequestAccessAsync().  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx

Comment: Thanks. MaintenanceTrigger only runs on AC power, so not really working for me. Should I conclude that the only way to pull-update Live Tile on the background without asking permission from the user is either via MaintenanceTrigger (that requires AC), or StartPeriodicUpdate (that requires external endpoint Uri)? I'd just want to get new value from App XML file every 24 hours and update that to Live Tile...external system feels a bit overkill :(

Comment: If you want it to run periodically regardless of whether it is plugged in, you need to RequestAccessAsync().

Comment: Can you please add that to the Answer, and I can accept it. Thank you for all the help Michael!